# java mismatch when assigning list of subclasses to list of superclasses

Tags: java, generics, superclass, type-mismatch

I've got an abstract class PricingProblemSover:

```
public abstract class PricingProblemSolver<T,U extends Column<T,U>, V extends PricingProblem<T, U>> implements Callable<Void>{ }
```

And some classes which extend this solver, for example:

```
public class ExactPricingProblemSolver extends PricingProblemSolver<CuttingStock, CuttingPattern, CuttingStockPricingProblem> { }
```

Where CuttingPattern and CuttingStockPricingProblem are resp. defined as:

```
public class CuttingPattern extends Column<CuttingStock, CuttingPattern> {}
public class CuttingStockPricingProblem extends PricingProblem<CuttingStock, CuttingPattern> {}
```

Now I need a List of solverClasses:

```
List<Class<PricingProblemSolver<CuttingStock, CuttingPattern, CuttingStockPricingProblem>>> solvers=Arrays.asList(ExactPricingProblemSolver.class);
```

This list will be used by a factory class to produce a large number of instances of these solvers for each problem instance.

The above List code gives however the following error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Class<ExactPricingProblemSolver>> to List<Class<PricingProblemSolver<CuttingStock,CuttingPattern,CuttingStockPricingProblem>>>
```

I'm not sure why this goes wrong. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: This is a well-known... "behaviour" of Java. a `List<Class<ExactPricingProblemSolver>>` is a different type than `List<Class<PrcingProblemSolver<...>>>`, even if `ExactPricingProblemSolver` extends `PricingProblemSolver`. The only workaround i can imagine is: Make a `List<Class<PricingProblemSolver>>` and store your `ExactPricingProblemSolver<...>`s in that list. The list can take object of child-classes.

Comment: @Turing85 what do you mean by "behaviour". Are you suggesting there is some way to have type safe generics without PECS?

Comment: `Class<ExactPricingProblemSolver>` would be `Class<? extends PricingProblemSolver<CuttingStock, CuttingPattern, CuttingStockPricingProblem>>`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider No, i do not suggest anything. But i am quite confident that it would be possible to support inheritance of generics within a language from the get-go, i.e. enabling the syntax OP wrote. Java just does not support it and thus "behaves" differently.

Comment: @Turing85 this has absolutely **nothing** to do with the implementation. If it a fundamental _requirement_ to ensure type safety.

Comment: @BoristheSpider of couse is has not. That is, why it was targeted to you. It was just to answer your question why i used the word "behaviour" =)